# How does KSum have minimum runtime of O(N^k-1)?

Tags: algorithm

In KSum problems, for example in 3Sum problems, there is a method to sort the array first, and then pick the first number. Next is to do the 2Sum for the rest of the array, resulting the total runtime of O(N^2). I find it hard to comprehend though. Since we have to do 2Sum about N-2 times, the total runtime still should be O(N^3). Please enlighten me.

Comment: Well, you do 2-sum for a smaller array each time you pick another number and the 2-sum is optimized because it is already sorted so its a bit less than O(n).

Comment: in a 5 sum problem, according to your approach you pick a number and then perform 4sum, which would pick a number and perform 3sum, and so on

Comment: @apokryfos I see. I was confused about 2Sun, that's why. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose **T(n, k)** denotes the time complexity required to compute a Ksum problem for an **sorted** array of size n. the base cases are

```
T(n, 1) = n
T(n, 2) = n
```

now for every other k we would have to loop once through the array and check if the k-1 sum is possible from the other elements so

```
T(n, 3) = n*T(n, 2)
T(n, 4) = n*T(n, 3)
....
T(n, k) = n*T(n, k-1)
```

so for k>2 the time complexity would be

> O(n^(k-1))